# How does one see the historic visitor data of EOS.IO Stack Exchange?

Tags: statistics

I'm curious if there has been an increase of visitors to EOS.IO Stack Exchange. How can one see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see *current* general site stats on the [Area 51 site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/116927/eosio) while still in beta but you cannot view stats over time.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have [5000 reputation](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics), you get access to site analytics which includes the daily number of visits. There's [only one user](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) with enough reputation to do so, but the ♦ moderators have access as well.

To get an idea of how it looks like: [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337649/295232) I posted some examples from other sites in the network. The image below is traffic for **Meta Stack Exchange, not EOS.IO Stack Exchange**.

[image]